# How do I make my square of random colours go up and then come back down in the same manner it went up -- leaving a black screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So far, this is my code.. I am not sure exactly how to make it go up once and then make it come back down in the same manner only once and leaving the user with a black screen. I tried doing this with the code, however it just ended up flipping it and going from large to small. The order I want it in is small to large and then large to small again -- if that makes sense.

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
screen_size = (700, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

for x in range(700, 0, -1):
    rand_colour = ((random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, rand_colour, (0, 0, x+1, x+1))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (0, 0, x, x))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.get()

for x in range(700):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,((random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))),(1*x,1*x,700,700))

for xy in range(700):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(700,700,-xy,-xy))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.time.wait(1)    


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Im a bit confused on what you want to achieve, Do you want the size of the square to go small to big then back to small? Also you usually have a game loop in pygame, are you not using one or unaware of it?

Comment: @TheBigKahuna I want to make the square go from small to big and then back to small. And im unaware about that, is it possible you could help me out a little?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so instead of having a few for loops, a game loop is a while loop that runs until the user wants to quit(usually through the X at the top right). You will notice in your program after the for loops, the window closes, this is the fix.

Lets start with the setup, this is the same as your program

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = (500,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)

running = True #this is true while the game is running
```

The next step is the loop

```py
while running: #loop while the game is running

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #get all events (eg. clicks, key presses, key ups, ETC)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the user clicked the X button
            running = False #stop running the program

pygame.quit() #after the loop is finished, quit pygame
```

This creates a blank window and closes it when you press the X button.

Next is to draw on the screen

```py
while running:
    screen.fill(black) #clear the screen

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,(100,100,100,100)) #draw a red rectangle at (100,100) that is 100x100

    pygame.display.update() #update the screen, exact same as using flip()
```

now that we have a red rectangle on the screen, lets resize it, we'll make variables for the size like you did in the for loop

```py
size = 100
dsize = -1
...
while running:
    ...
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,(100,100,size,size)) #draw a red rectangle at (100,100) that is 100x100

    size += dsize  #change the size
    if size < 10 or size > 100: #if size is outside safe sizes
        dsize *= -1  #reverse the direction
```

it may seem a bit fast, but you cant go less than 1, so what you can do is use a clock from pygame to limit the fps

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
...
while running:
    ...
    clock.tick(60) #limit the fps to 60
    print(clock.get_fps()) #this is not necessary, but if you change 60 to 0, you can see how fast it was going
```